# SQL: Take maximum value, but if a field is missing for a particular ID, ignore all values

Tags: sql

This is somewhat difficult to explain...(this is using SQL Assistant for Teradata, which I'm not overly familiar with).

```
ID         creation_date        completion_date       Difference
123          5/9/2016             5/16/2016             7
123          5/14/2016            5/16/2016             2
456          4/26/2016            4/30/2016             4
456          (null)               4/30/2016             (null)
789          3/25/2016            3/31/2016             6
789          3/1/2016             3/31/2016             30
```

An ID may have more than one creation_date, but it will always have the same completion_date.  If the creation_date is populated for all records for an ID, I want to return the record with the most recent creation_date.  However, if ANY creation_date for a given ID is missing, I want to ignore all records associated with this ID.

Given the data above, I would want to return:

```
ID         creation_date        completion_date       Difference
123          5/14/2016            5/16/2016             2
789          3/25/2016            3/31/2016             6
```

No records are returned for 456 because the second record has a missing creation_date.  The record with the most recent creation_date is returned for 123 and 789.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and tag your database...

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(creation_date) = COUNT(*)`

Comment: As an aside, do you need to store "difference"? In Teradata I believe you can compute the difference in days as "date1" - "date2".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database, here's one option using `row_number` to get the `max` date per group.  You can then filter those results with `not exists` to check against `null` values:

```
select *
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by id order by creation_date desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1 and not exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t2.creationdate is null and t.id = t2.id
)
```

`row_number` is a `window function` that is supported in many databases.  `mysql` doesn't but you can achieve the same result using `user-defined variables`.

---

Here is a more generic version using `conditional aggregation`:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
    join (select id, max(creation_date) max_creation_date
          from yourtable
          group by id
          having count(case when creation_date is null then 1 end) = 0
    ) t2 on t.id = t2.id and t.creation_date = t2.max_creation_date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a2e7f/1)

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to make the latter query work and it seems to work as intended!